# Proof of the Primitive Existence Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, proof-explanation

In the first section of the proof of the primitive existence theorem we are trying to show that $$F\left(z+h\right)-F\left(z\right)=\int_{L_{z,z+h}}f$$ where $\alpha, z,z+h$ are collinear and $\alpha=z+xh$ where $h\neq0$

The proof is, 
$$F\left(z+h\right)-F\left(z\right)=\int_{L_{\alpha,z+h}}f-\int_{L_{\alpha,z}}f\\
=\int^{1}_{0}f\left(\alpha+\left(z+h-\alpha\right)t\right)\left(z+h-\alpha\right)dt-\int^{1}_{0}f\left(\alpha+\left(z-\alpha\right)t\right)\left(z-\alpha\right)dt\\
=h\left(1-x\right)\int^{1}_{0}f\left(z+xh+\left(h-xh\right)t\right)dt+xh\int^{1}_{0}f\left(z+xh-xht\right)dt\\
=h\int^{1}_{x}f\left(z+hs\right)ds-h\int^{0}_{x}f\left(z+hs\right)ds\\
=h\int^{1}_{0}f\left(z+hs\right)ds\\
=\int_{L_{z,z+h}}f$$

Could someone please explain how to go from the 3rd line of the above proof to the 4th? I'm unsure of what $s$ is or where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a substitution. Set $s=x+(1-x)t.$ Then $ds=(1-x)dt$ and the limits change from $t\in[0,1]$ to $s\in[x,1]$.

Comment: Thanks, I see this now for the first integral of the 3rd line but could you explain this for the second integral? I can't see how to turn (z+xh-xht) into (z+hs) using s=x+(1-x)t

Comment: @SophieFiler: Whoops, I didn't even look at the second integral. In that case the substitution is $s=x-xt$, so $ds=-xdt$. You can work this out for yourself just by comparing the integrals in line 3 with the corresponding integrals in line 4. It's just a matter of pattern matching.